# Abreviação de "separadamente"

Tags: abreviações

Com a correria do dia-a-dia é comum utilizarmos abreviaturas. Na tarde de hoje, lendo um artigo de jornal, me deparei com uma não familiar.

Por isto, resolvi recorrer ao "Stack" para saber se o que eu estava lendo era algo correto ou uma *"Gaff"*.

Então pergunto:

- A palavra *separadamente* pode ser abreviada pela palavra "separa" seguida de duas barras (//), desta forma: **separada//**?

Comment: poderia mencionar o artigo?

Comment: Nos meus tempos de estudante eu usava uma barra, /, para abreviar qualquer advérbio em *-mente*, *separa/, consequente/*, etc. Mas em jornais, livros, ou qualquer escrita minimamente formal só se usam abreviações consagradas (Sr., Dr.).